# Information theory riddle about finding a gift in one of 16 boxes

Tags: puzzle, information-theory

There are $16$ boxes, one of which contains the gift. We have $7$ persons, who can help us by answering on any yes/no question, but one of the persons is a liar, he **may not** tell us the truth. We have one question with each of $7$ persons. Our goal is to say definitely which one of $16$ boxes contains the gift.

(The problem is from information theory and I guess it is connected to some error correction code.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice problem. Question: Doe the liar always lie or  randomly? Then, please tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do the truth-tellers know who is the liar and can tell us?

Comment: Do these 7 people know where the gift is?

Comment: tellers only  know where the gift is, liar lies randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expected and Hagen von Eitzen also pointed out, you could use an error-correcting code that encodes $4$ bits of information (the position of the gift) with $7$ bits (the yes-no questions you ask from the $7$ people) and is capable of correcting a single error.  The [$(7,4)$-Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)) code is one such code.

So, we could do as follows:

1. The code consists of $16$ distinct $7$-bit code words that are at Hamming distance at least $3$ from one another.  Assign these code words to the boxes in a one-to-one fashion.
2. Ask the $i$'th person the following: *Is the $i$'th bit of the code word of the box containing the gift $1$ (yes) or $0$ (no)?*
3. The result is a $7$-bit word that is either a code word or differs at a single bit from one and only one of the code words.  The gift is in the box identified by that code word.

Answer (score 5):

We need to obtain 4 bits of information and can query 7 bits, but with one possible error. This smells a lot like [Hamming code](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming-Code).

Comment: I guess it is, but cant translate to yes/no style solution

Comment: A yes/no is the same as a 0/1 ..